# How to multiply each pixel of a ImageCollection by a single value

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using the python EarthEngine API, Is it possible having a `ee.ImageCollection` to multiply all pixels of all the images by a single value `val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible by using a `.map()` call.

```
test = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image.constant(5), ee.Image.constant(10)])
val = 2
test_multi = test.map(lambda image: image.multiply(val))

print(test_multi)
```

Let me know if this works. I'm mostly working in the javascript editor, but the conversion to Python should be quite straight-forward.